# Testing Backbone Model's trigger method with Jasmine

Tags: testing, backbone.js, jasmine

I got a weird error when testing the trigger method of my Backbone model. Below is my code:

```
Category = Backbone.Model.extend({
   fetchNotes: function() {
     this.trigger("notesFetchedEvent");
   }
})

describe("Category", function() {

 it("should fetch notes", function() {
   var category = new Category;
   spyOn(category, "trigger");
   category.fetchNotes();
   expect(category.trigger).wasCalledWith("notesFetchedEvent");
 })

})
```

The error I got was "Expected spy trigger to have been called with [ 'notesFetchedEvent' ] but was called with ...jibberish...". Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Worked fine for me under jasmine1.1.0-rc1  Maybe something is causing a javascript error?  Check your console.

Comment: Could you try it with ´expect(category.trigger).toHaveBeenCalledWith("notesFetchedEvent")´ as ´ wasCalledWith` is deprecated.

Comment: toHaveBeenCalledWith doesn't work for me. The code above is just sample code to illustrate my point. My full code is at http://pastie.org/private/ttkougq7n7jg4zx3hliq(category model) and http://pastie.org/private/uh4dxauteb7qvt6pgkp1hq (test)

Comment: I figured out why, it was because the trigger method that I wanted to test is in the ajax callback while the one in expect() is the trigger called everytime a Backbone model's set() is called

Comment: @TriVuong Can you detail how you fixed that issue?

Answer (score 4):

I've found that often the best way to test event triggering is to register a spy as one of the listeners on the event instead of spying on the trigger method directly. This would look something like this:

```
describe("Category", function() {
  it("should fetch notes", function() {
    var category = new Category();
    var spy = jasmine.createSpy('event');
    category.on('notesFetchedEvent', spy);
    category.fetchNotes();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```